# Normalize tab spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project that has code that was contributed by many people without a proper policy on tab space (I know, huge mistake.)

What's the best way to normalize all tabs to spaces? Optimally some kind of a script that can do this to all files via the command line at once.

I know of [Ruby Beautifier](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html), but I didn't have any luck with ERB files (it also doesn't run on 1.9).

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**:
Forgot to say that we use Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command line utility bundled with OS X called [tab2space](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tab2space.1.html) that you might find useful. It's probably available on other platforms too.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say open all files in Notepad++ and replace "\t" with "  " (or 4 spaces) with the usual replace dialog. You'll have to choose 'Extended' in the lower left corner and press "Replace in all opened documents".